# ZKP, Gnark: Does AssertIsLessOrEqual work with negative numbers?

Tags: zkp, gnark, bn254

Does gnarks (ZeroKnowledgeProof framework) AssertIsLessOrEqual work with negative numbers and ecc.BN254 curve?
https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/consensys/gnark@v0.7.0/frontend

It seems most computations including multiplication works with negative numbers but AssertIsLessOrEqual does not work as expected when it has negative parameters.

Answer (score 3):

gnark/bn254 works with unsigned numbers. When you pass `-3` then it is `21888242871839275222246405745257275088548364400416034343698204186575808495614`

What may mislead as `frontend.API.Println` will print `21888242871839275222246405745257275088548364400416034343698204186575808495614` as `-3`

`AssertIsLessOrEqual` will consider `-3` as `21888242871839275222246405745257275088548364400416034343698204186575808495614`