# How to implement a >=0 check in gnark for unsigned integers when a can be any integer (negative or positive) in the clear?

Tags: go, zk-snark, zkp, gnark, bn254

I have the following block of code in `golang` in the clear.

```
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
     if val[i]>=0{
        postcheck[i] = val[i]
        bitpostcheck[i] = 1
     } else {
        postcheck[i] = 0
        bitpostcheck[i] = 0
     }
}
```

`val[i]` can be a negative or positive integer in the clear.

I translated the above code into `gnark` as follows:

```
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    postcheck[i] = api.Select(val[i], val[i], frontend.Variable(0))
    bitpostcheck[i] = api.Select(val[i], frontend.Variable(1), frontend.Variable(0))
}
```

Here `val`, postcheck and bitpostcheck are all `[10]frontend.Variable.`

But I am getting an `assertIsBoolean error`, since in `gnark` the first variable of `Select` should be either `0` or `1` but `val[i]` can basically be any *unsigned* integer.

Since `gnark` only deals with *unsigned* integers, negative integers are represented as huge positive numbers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71826404/zkp-gnark-does-assertislessorequal-work-with-negative-numbers) in `gnark`.

Given all this information, how do I implement the `golang` clear code in `gnark`? basically the check `val[i]>=0`?

Comment: What does "in the clear" mean?

Comment: Meaning in golang simply, without gnark.

Comment: `api.Select` returns `frontend.Variable` type. You need to type _assertion_.  Example -> `postcheck[i] = api.Select(val[i], val[i], frontend.Variable(0)).(int)`

Comment: This doesn't work. Such kind of conversions are not allowed in gnark.